# Basis for the vector space of linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

So I just finished reading that the set of linear transformations $L(V,W)$  from a vector space V to a vector space W (both over a field $F$) is a vector space itself if we define addition and scalar multiplication for arbitrary linear transformations $T,U\in L(V,W)$  as and  follows:

$(T+U)(x)=T(x)+U(x)$ and for $a\in F$ $(aT)(x)=aT(x)$.

My question is, can one construct a basis for this vector space?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In fact, we can construct LOTS of bases. One possible basis, given a basis $\{v_i\}$ for $V$, and a basis $\{w_j\}$ for $W$, is the set of linear transformations $\{T_{ij}\}$ where $T_{ij}(v_i) = w_j$ and $T_{ij}(v_k) = 0, k \neq i$.

Comment: I'm surprised I didn't see that haha. Thank you.